# Running a Docker image from ECR on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a docker image in ECR.  I want to run it in ECS.  I've followed the steps in the AWS docs which take me [here](https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ecs/home?region=us-east-2#/firstRun).  That runs through a series of steps that set up some kind of ECS cluster, but it never asks which docker image in ECR that I want to run.

Running a docker image is very simple, but ECS seems overly complex for what I'm trying to do (run a docker image of a simple web service).  [This](http://blog.jimtough.com/docker-on-aws-part-2-creating-an-ecs-cluster-to-host-the-docker-image/) is the best explanation I've found.  Maybe I've missed something.

Amazon's docs seem to go off on tangents and never get back to a docker image in ECR.  Is there a better explanation of how run an ECR image in ECS?

Edit:  adding task definition json:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::504084722442:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/first-run-task-definition",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [
        "sh",
        "-c"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "/bin/sh -c \"echo '<html> <head> <title>Amazon ECS Sample App</title> <style>body {margin-top: 40px; background-color: #333;} </style> </head><body> <div style=color:white;text-align:center> <h1>Amazon ECS Sample App</h1> <h2>Congratulations!</h2> <p>Your application is now running on a container in Amazon ECS.</p> </div></body></html>' >  /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html && httpd-foreground\""
      ],
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 256,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 512,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "image": "504084722442.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dean.w.schulze.5040",
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "sample-app"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "512",
  "taskRoleArn": null,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-2:504084722442:task-definition/first-run-task-definition:2",
  "family": "first-run-task-definition",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "256",
  "revision": 2,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: [Getting Started with Amazon ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted_EC2.html) in the AWS documentation has a minimum number of steps to run an image, but it's still "several".  Nothing stops you from just running Docker on an EC2 instance if you find that easier and sufficiently maintainable.

Comment: That doc is very confusing.  I'm using an existing ECR image.  In step 2 (Create Task Definition) it says to use the full tag name for an ECR image in the container definition.  I guess I have to edit the container definition instead of the task definition.  Can you clarify this?

When put the ECR  image URL in the container definition Image it gives `Some selected container options are invalid or empty.`

Comment: Can you post your task definition in json format?

Comment: Added the task defn. json.  It added my docker image, but it also looks like it is using the sample-app instead of running my docker image.

Answer (score 1):

I understand there is little confusion when you talk about how to run docker image on ECS. I have listed some key concepts which will make ECS easy for you.

**Cluster**: To use ECS on AWS the first thing you have to do is create a Cluster. Creating a cluster is simple because you only have to chose among the following two main types of template.

- **EC2**: This cluster can only run the task definition which are configured to run image on an EC2 instance. It is just like creating an EC2 instance and running a docker image on it.
- **Fargate**: In a fargate cluster an EC2 instance is not created, instead it only creates the network interface on EC2 services. You can still assign a public IP and view your container image based on the your task definition.

**Task Definition**: You can think of a task definition as a place to define your container image. This task definition is used to run a task inside the cluster . You can define everything related to a docker image in your task definition i.e. anything that can be done with `docker run` command, can be configured in a task definition.

**Service**: The service uses the task definition to run a task. For example, you have one docker image and you want at least two instances always running your image. You can set the number of instance while configuring the service as two and ECS service will make sure that two tasks are always running  your image inside the cluster. If a tasks goes down for a reason, it will keep trying to run your task.

**Task**: The task is the entity in ECS which actually runs your docker image. A task can be spawned using a service or by creating a new task directly. In both the cases you must have a task definition which contains the information about your docker image.

**Answer to your comment:**

*"I guess I have to edit the container definition instead of the task definition"*.

Well, the container definition is the task definition. If you want to update the image, you can create a new revision of the task definition and use this revision to run your task. If you are running your task through a service, you can update the service and assign the latest task definition. The service will automatically spawn a new task with the latest task definition. To use an ECR image just copy the url from the icon beside the image name and paste it under 'Image' in the task definition.

*Note*: You should have a public ip enabled and/or internet connectivity to the instance(EC2)/network interface (fargate) to connect to ECR, read [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr).

Comment: The Task -> Details page has a public IP address, but I can't connect to it.  When deployed locally I connect to localhost:8080/api/hello, but when deployed to AWS 
 the <PUBLIC_IP>:8080/api/hello gives "refused to connect".  The docs say to click on the ENI Id to get the public IP, but there is nothing in the table.  Docs are simply wrong on this point.

Comment: The link you provided is for something called a PrivateLink, which is not mentioned in the ECS Getting Started.  PrivateLink involves ECR and S3.  Is this really necessary to deploy a simple docker image in ECS?

Comment: Regarding your second comment, the link that I shared was just informative and related to how to run an ECS task in a private subnet. I am  not sure which ECS 'Gettting Started' document you are referring to on AWS but I am guessing it would be related to basic setup. They usually do not mention complicated setup such as of running a task in a private subnet in 'Getting Started' documents . If you are doing a basic setup of running an ECS task in a public subnet, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Regarding you first comment, you are right the public IP will come on the Task detail page. Check for two things: (1) Did you define port mappings at port 8080 in your task definition? I looked at your task definition and you have mapped port 80, you have to change it to port 8080. (2) Open ENI (network interface), open the security group associated with it, make sure an Inbound TCP rule is added at port 8080 to accept traffic from anywhere.